# Trying to use CTE to replace codes with names

Tags: sql, sql-server

Expecting to get names instead of codes which is highlighted in yellow.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Employee Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_Employees](
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Employees] ([Name], [Code]) VALUES (N'A', N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Employees] ([Name], [Code]) VALUES (N'B', N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Employees] ([Name], [Code]) VALUES (N'C', N'3')
GO
```

**Data Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_Details](
    [Department] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Zone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Place] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [L1] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [L2] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [L3] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Details] ([Department], [Zone], [Place], [City], [L1], [L2], [L3]) VALUES (N'Department1', N'Zone1', N'Place1', N'City1', N'1         ', N'2         ', N'3         ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Details] ([Department], [Zone], [Place], [City], [L1], [L2], [L3]) VALUES (N'Department2', N'Zone2', N'Place2', N'City2', N'3         ', N'2         ', N'1         ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Details] ([Department], [Zone], [Place], [City], [L1], [L2], [L3]) VALUES (N'Department3', N'Zone3', N'Place3', N'City3', N'2         ', N'3         ', N'1         ')
GO
```

**My Attempt**

```
WITH _Details AS 
( 
    SELECT L1 FROM _Details 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT e.Name FROM _Employees e INNER JOIN _Details d  ON e.Code = d.L1 
) 
SELECT * FROM _Details
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I also posted sql statements which generates those image data.

Comment: And why are you storing L1, L2, L3 as nchar if it takes an int? You really should use the correct datatype for the job. It will avoid all sorts of issues in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `JOIN` the tables:

```
SELECT 
   d.[Department], d.[Zone], d.[Place], d.[City], 
   e1.[Name] AS L1, e2.[Name] AS L2, e3.[Name] AS L3
FROM _Details d
LEFT JOIN _Employees e1 ON d.L1 = e1.Code
LEFT JOIN _Employees e2 ON d.L2 = e2.Code
LEFT JOIN _Employees e3 ON d.L3 = e3.Code
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need joins. Join the employee table thrice, once per employee column. As L1, L2, and L3 are nullable, you need outer joins.

```
select
  d.[Department], d.[Zone], d.[Place], d.[City],
  e1.[Name] as name1,
  e2.[Name] as name2,
  e3.[Name] as name3
from [dbo].[_Details] d
left join [dbo].[_Employees] e1 on e1.[Code] = d.[L1]
left join [dbo].[_Employees] e2 on e2.[Code] = d.[L3]
left join [dbo].[_Employees] e3 on e3.[Code] = d.[L2];
```

Comment: Oh, seems I was a little late with my answer :-)